# Problem assigning null to simulated generic nullable data types

Tags: delphi, nullable, delphi-xe5

I am trying to create a nullable data type in Delphi:

```
type
  TNullable<T> = record
  public
    Value: T;
    IsNull: Boolean;
    class operator Implicit(const AValue: T): TNullable<T>;
    class operator Implicit(const AValue: TNullable<T>): T;
    class operator Implicit(const AValue: Variant): TNullable<T>;
    class operator Explicit(const AValue: T): TNullable<T>;
  end;
```

So far so good, but what to assign as a `null` literal so that the nullable data type remains of its basic type? For example:

```
var
  v: TNullable<Integer>;
begin
  //What type is this "null"? A Variant null?
  //How TNullable<Integer> could remain of Integer after the assignment?
  v := null;

  //How to compare this "null"? Compare to what type?
  if v = null then begin
  end;
end;
```

Let us assume that `null` is the variant null:

```
class operator TNullable<T>.Implicit(const AValue: Variant): TNullable<T>;
begin
  if VarIsNull(AValue) or VarIsClear(AValue) then begin
    Result.IsNull := True;
    Result.Value := Default(T);
  end
  else begin
    Result.IsNull := False;
    Result.Value := AValue; //Version 1: Incompatible types: 'T' and 'Variant'!!!
    Result.Value := T(AValue); //Version 2: Invalid typecast!!!
    //Should I write a big "case" block here in order to handle each data type?!
  end;
end;
```

Do you have ideas?

Comment: T, and hence Value can be of any type, including things that variant is not assignment compatible with, such as records, for instance. I know (well, assume) you only intend to use compatible types but the compiler can't know that

Comment: There are of course many ways to crate a `TNullable<T>`. Personally, I think I'd do it without involving variants. So my null symbol would not be `null`, but of a custom type.

Comment: An empty record would suffice, either as a separate type, or as a nested type of `TNullable`. The alternative would be to instead simply add a `SetNull()` method to `TNullable`.

Comment: @Paul `null` is an actual keyword in C#, similar to `nullptr` in C++11.  They are both distinct and have special handling by the compiler. The closest thing in Delphi right now is `nil`, but that will likely cause conflicts if `T` is a reference type. So in Delphi, declaring a distinct type for your `null` value, such as an empty record, is the next best thing if you want to use assignment syntax on `TNullable` values.

Comment: There are severe design issues: 1) You should hide TNullable<T> record internals in `private` section. 2) Persisting null state in `IsNull` field isn't a good idea. When you construct `default(TNullable<T>)` it will have its `IsNull` initialized to false, which is probably not what you want. You should better call it `HasValue` .. [similar to C#](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Null` in this case is indeed a `Variant`, see [`System.Variants.Null`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.Null).  Using a `Variant` in this situation is not a good idea, in part because of the assignment troubles you are seeing with it.

A better option is to define a distinct type to represent your `null` values (similar to `nullptr_t` in C++11 and later), eg:

```pascal
type
  TNullValue = record
  end;

  TNullable<T{: record}> = record
  public
    Value: T;
    HasValue: Boolean;

    class operator Implicit(const AValue: T): TNullable<T>;
    class operator Implicit(const AValue: TNullable<T>): T;
    class operator Implicit(const AValue: TNullValue): TNullable<T>;
    class operator Explicit(const AValue: T): TNullable<T>;

    // add these...
    class operator Equal(const A: TNullable<T>; const B: TNullValue): Boolean;
    class operator NotEqual(const A: TNullable<T>; const B: TNullValue): Boolean;
    ...
  end;

const
  NullValue: TNullValue;

...

class operator TNullable<T>.Implicit(const AValue: T): TNullable<T>;
begin
  Result.Value := AValue;
  Result.HasValue := True;
end;

class operator TNullable<T>.Implicit(const AValue: TNullable<T>): T;
begin
  if AValue.HasValue then
    Result := AValue.Value
  else
    Result := Default(T); // or raise an exception
end;

class operator TNullable<T>.Implicit(const AValue: TNullValue): TNullable<T>;
begin
  Result.Value := Default(T);
  Result.HasValue := False;
end;

class operator TNullable<T>.Explicit(const AValue: T): TNullable<T>;
begin
  Result.Value := AValue;
  Result.HasValue := True;
end;

class operator TNullable<T>.Equal(const A: TNullable<T>; const B: TNullValue): Boolean;
begin
  Result := not A.HasValue;
end;

class operator TNullable<T>.NotEqual(const A: TNullable<T>; const B: TNullValue): Boolean;
begin
  Result := A.HasValue;
end;
```

```pascal
var
  v: TNullable<Integer>;
begin
  v := NullValue;

  if v = NullValue then begin
    ...
  end;

  if v <> NullValue then begin
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Does it make sense to use the `record` [constraint](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Constraints_in_Generics#Record_Constraint) on `T`?  Presumably OP wants this only for value types.

Comment: @J... Probably so, but it really depends on the OP's use case.  For instance, the OP is looking for something similar to C# nullables, and C# 8 added the concept of nullable reference types.

Comment: Presumably we could allow assigning `nil` (with appropriate operator) instead of `TNullValue` if the constraint precluded reference types as `T`, though... assuming OP wanted that behaviour.  Delphi objects are already 'nullable' in the sense that this would allow `nil` to assign null to value and reference types.  This doesn't distingush null from unassigned, of course.  Just not sure if there are other consequences to such a design...

Comment: @J... if `T` allows reference types, then allowing `nil` will require an operator accepting `Pointer`, which will conflict with operators accepting `T`, and you have the issue of deciding whether assigning a `nil` will set `HasValue` to True or False. "*This doesn't distingush null from unassigned, of course*" - exactly. For a reference type, there would be a difference between a nullable holding no value at all, vs a nullable holding a `nil` value.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  It would require the `record` constraint on `T` to preclude this.